# Como chamar função dentro de outra função em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Oi, pessoal.
Sou nova no Python e preciso entregar um script de requests APIs.
Existem três atributos necessários para requisitar a API (client_id, client_secret e texto), sendo que as duas "clients" são informações sensíveis e não podem ir exibidas no script.

Criei funções no arquivo config para levar essas duas informações, e no script principal quero chamar. A questão é que não estou conseguindo chamar.

```
     def get_client_id():
         Config().get_client_id ##essa função chama o client_id que está no arquivo Config.py
    
     def get_client_secret():
         Config().get_client_secret ##essa função chama o client_id que está no arquivo Config.py
    
resp = NomeApi().request_api({self.get_client_id()}, {self.get_client_secret()}, texto="Q1JFQVRFIEVYVEVSTkFMIFR=")

#os get_clients não estão conseguindo chamar o valor que está na classe Config.py
```

---

Legenda:
NomeApi() é a classe que contém todas as funções
request_api() é a função principal para requisitar a API

Comment: Meu palpite é que está faltando os parênteses ao final para chamar os métodos (ex: `Config().get_client_id()`). Mas sem ver o código inteiro é difícil adivinhar.

Comment: Obrigada pelo toque. Eu coloquei o parênteses pra manter as boas práticas, mas ele rodou sem também.
Consegui uma solução e coloquei na resposta abaixo. Valeuss!!

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. No seu caso, como vc mesma encontrou a solução, basta [marcar a sua resposta abaixo como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido (como foi vc mesma que respondeu, acho que o sistema só permite que vc faça isso depois de algumas horas, mas enfim, basta aguardar o prazo...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui uma solução.

Consegui chamar a função que estava em outro arquivo (no meu caso Config.py) e rodar nesse script. Assim a requisição retornou certinha.

```
def get_client_id(cls):
        Config().get_client_id

    def get_client_secret(cls):
        Config().get_client_secret


resp = NomeApi().request_api(f"{Config().get_client_id()}", f"{Config().get_client_secret()}",
                               texto="Q1JFQVRHAJSOksuasnjJA=")
```